# Differentiating a vector?

Tags: derivatives, vectors

I am having doubt with i think a pretty simple question.

I want to know how the vector in the following question id differentiated.

**Question:**
    If **s** is a vector function, of the scalar **t**, whose module is **r** and **a**,**b** are constant vectors, differentiate the following with regard to t.
       $$r^{3}.s + a.s'$$

where **s'** means it is differentiated once.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since vectors-valued functions are easy to differentiate (just differentiate each component), there is no difficulty in differentiating the second term: $D(as')=as''$. And since the product rule still holds here, we can differentiate the first term as

$$D(r^3s)=3r^2D(r)s+r^3s'$$

and the only difficulty here is figuring out $D(r)$.

Since $r=(s\cdot s)^{1/2}$, we can apply the chain rule and the product rule to obtain

$$D(r)=(1/2) (s\cdot s)^{-1/2}D(s\cdot s)=(1/2) (s\cdot s)^{-1/2}(2 s\cdot s')=\frac{s\cdot s'}{\sqrt{s\cdot s}}.$$

Now, just put everything together.

Comment: @Aron thanks for the answer but i knew that. Actually the answer is confusing me there is some part which i am missing while understanding it.  Here is the answer .. $$3r^{2}r's + r^{3}s' + a{\times}s"$$             can you explain me the answer i think that will help me

Comment: Thanks @Aron i got the hint to understand it from your answer

Comment: @Dimensionless The only other thing I can think to explain is that the usual product rule for differentiation not only holds when you multiply two scalar functions, but also when you multiply a scalar and a vector, or when you take the dot product of two vectors.